# Comparing fuzzy filenames

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Sometimes humans make an error or intentionally make text difficult to read.
For example,

```
1 Queen Live At Hammersmith Odeon 1975 FULL GREAT SOUND.mp4
2 Queen Live at Hammersmith Odeon 1979 FULL CLEAN SOUND.mp4
3 QUEEN The Legendary Concert (Full Concert 1975).mp4
```

First of all, 1 and 3 are the same (only Queen fan knows and probably not possible to find the difference for a machine; considering the Terminator comes from the future). now I want to put some new files into this list.

```
1 Queen Live At Hammersmith Odeon 1975 FULL GREAT SOUND.mp4    
2 Queen Live at Hammersmith Odeon 1979 FULL CLEAN SOUND.mp4    
3 QUEEN The Legendary Concert (Full Concert 1975).mp4    
4 Queen Live At The Rainbow 1974 FULL CLEAN SOUND 2013 Complet.mp4    
5 Queen Live att Hammersmith Odean 1975 FULL GREAT SOUND.mp4
6 Quëen Live At H4mm3rsm1th Odeon 1975 FULL GREAT SOUND.mp4
```

I realized that only #4 is new and #5 and #6 are exactly the same ones, #5 looks like when I am drunk or too tired, and #6 is a particular retrospective anti-search-engine model. For humans, #1, (#3) #5 and #6 are the duplicated files (concert).

Can we code a shell script which tells the keywords(s) match N% to the files?
When I use a keyword `queen live hammersmith odeon 1975` it should suggest #1, #2, #5 and #6

Comment: If you simply want to search for records in a file, use `grep -i -e "<key>" -e "<key2>"... filename` which shall fetch you the records you searched. However, if you want `#5` and `#6` to get identified you need an AI solution for it.

Comment: @iamhrishikesh, yes that is the exact point of the question, how similar they are. E.g. Odeon and Odean is 1 letter (20%) different, in other word "Can we compare two strings and show stat result and sort?"